# Correcting records with similar attendeeNames and

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large dataset,the client imported one event with incorrect attendeeID identifiers and no backup, so i have dates of birth and gender which are consistent, and names which are kinda similar

```
table Attendees
---------------
id int(10) not null auto_increment,
AttendeeName varchar(255) not null,
Gender char(1) not null,
AttendeeID int(8) not null,
EventName varchar(255) not null
```

A Person may attend many events

I can select the records I need to change with correct and incorrect IDs and Names

as an example I have

```
John McKenna 90001232 Event1
John Mc Kenna   95131 Event2
John Doe            0 Event1
John Doe     90001122 Event2
Henry Hynes         0 Event1
Henry Hynes  90001211 Event2
```

and I want to end up with

```
John McKenna 90001232 Event1
John McKenna 90001232 Event2 etc
```

and

I tried using

```
select distinct(s.AttendeeName) AS CORRECTNAME
    , st.AttendeeName AS INCORRECTNAME
    , s.AttendeeID AS CORRECTID
    , st.AttendeeID AS INCORRECTID 
from #__Events s 
inner join #__Events st 
   on s.DateOfBirth = st.DateOfBirth 
  and soundex(s.AttendeeName) = soundex(st.AttendeeName) 
where s.Gender = st.Gender 
  and length(s.AttendeeID)= 8 
  and length(st.AttendeeID) < 8 
  and s.AttendeeName != st.AttendeeName 
order by s.AttendeeName;
```

The problem is, i am not sure how to construct the update statement any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
update x4tst_seed_times dest, (select distinct(s.SwimmerName) as INCORRECTNAME,st.SwimmerName as CORRECTNAME, s.SwimIrelandID as CORRECTID, st.SwimIrelandID AS INCORRECTID from x4tst_seed_times s inner join x4tst_seed_times st on s.DateOfBirth = st.DateOfBirth and soundex(s.SwimmerName) = soundex(st.SwimmerName) where length(s.SwimIrelandID)= 8 and length(st.SwimIrelandID) < 8 order by s.SwimmerName) src
```

set dest.SwimIrelandID = src.CORRECTID, dest.SwimmerName = src.CORRECTNAME where dest.DateOfBirth = src.DateOfBirth and dest.SwimmerName = src.CORRECTSWIMMERNAME and dest.SwimIrelandID = src.INCORRECTID;